# Разница в js и jQuery в плане чтения файлов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, пишу функцию для чтения файлов и пытаюсь сделать это через jQuery.
Сам вопрос довольно шаткий и странный, но я не сдаюсь и нашел алгоритм наиболее подходящий для моей задачи. Однако есть одна проблема, которая заключается в ошибке. Прошу объясните мне в чем тут дело.

Если изменить строчку с

```
readFile(document.getElementById('file'));
```

На тоже самое только jQuery

```
readFile(($'#file'));
```

То выдает следующую ошибку

```
script.js:154 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

```js
function readFile(object) {
  var file = object.files[0]
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = function() {
    rawData = JSON.parse(reader.result);
  }
  reader.readAsText(file)
  $('svg').remove();
}

$('#file').change(function () {
   readFile(document.getElementById('file')); 
});


// общая функция которая при нажатии на кнопку вызывает остальные функции

$('.chart1').click(function () {
    $('svg').remove();
    readFile(document.getElementById('file'));
    console.log(rawData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file">
<button class="chart1">Read!</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('file')`  возвращает HTML DOM Object.

`$('#file')` возвращает jQuery Object.

Думаю, надо `readFile($('#file')[0]);`

Comment: Спасибо)
Прощу прощение за такой простой вопрос)

Comment: @СергейМатвеев рад, что помогло)

Answer (score 3):

Для начала, запись

```
readFile(($'#file'));
```

содержит синтаксическую ошибку. Наверное, подразумевалось такое

```
readFile($('#file'));
```

Ну а дальше все просто. Функция `readFile()` ожидает в качестве параметра элемент DOM. А функция `$()` возвращает набор jQuery. Это совершенно различные объекты.

Для получения конкретного объекта DOM из набора существует метод `get()`

```
readFile($('#file').get(0));
```

или можно обратиться к набору, как к массиву

```
readFile($('#file')[0]);
```